# Independent Events find P(A or B')

Tags: probability

Given that P(A and B)=0.1 and P(A and B')=0.4 find P(A or B') if A and B are independent.

The ans is 0.9

Please tell me the rule you use in the problem.

Comment: try making a table

Comment: Hints: Drawing a Venn diagram may help. Can you figure out the value of $P(A)$?  (Use the Third Axiom of Probability). Once you have that, can you figure out the value of $P(B)$? (Independence definition applied bass ackwards)

Answer (score 1):

Two events $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* if
$$
\Bbb P(X\text{ and }Y) = \Bbb P(X)\cdot\Bbb P(Y)
$$
We also have the general formulas
\begin{align*}
\Bbb P(X\text{ or }Y) &= \Bbb P(X)+\Bbb P(Y)-\Bbb P(X\text{ and }Y) \\
\Bbb P(X) &= 1-\Bbb P(X^\prime)
\end{align*}
Can you use these formulas to solve your problem?

Comment: I know all of those rule, but don't know how to apply to the problem.

Comment: So, P(A or B') = P(A)+P(B')-P(A and B'), right?

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem. NVM

0.1 = P(A)P(B)

P(A)=0.4+0.1

0.1 = 0.5P(B)

P(B) = 0.2

P(B')=0.8

P(A or B')=P(A)+P(B')-P(A and B')

= 0.5+0.8-0.4

=0.9

Answer (score 1):

By simply using the Venn diagram. It is clear that

P(A or B') = P(A) + P(B') -P(A and B')
          and
P(A and B') = P(A) - P(A and B), this implies that 0.4 = P(A) - 0.4, Therefore P(A) = 0.5

A and B are independent events, this means that P(A and B) = P(A)*P(B)
Therefore 0.1 = 0.5*P(B), P(B) = 0.2
Consequently, P(B') = 1 - 0.2 = 0.8

Finally, P(A or B') = 0.5 + 0.8 - 0.4 = 0.9